# Firebase timestamp filter

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to firebase, actually I'm trying to load some data based on timestamp and retrieve between two timestamp using startat and endat. Data is pushed through Python.

The data is as shown in the sample screenshot

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0dR6.png)

The data path popping-fire-7751.firebaseio.com/device488

```
activevolt: 396
avgPowerFactor: 0.95
avgThdi: 7.5
cubetemp: 37
datetime: "2016-02-08 15:16:32"
timestamp: 1454924792
totalPowerGen: 34
```

I'm pushing data through python setting the priority as timestamp.
When I try to filter  as shown here it returns null. But without startAt and endAt it shows all the values.

http://jsfiddle.net/casperkamal/EZUtP/64/

```
var startTime = 1454924792;
var endTime = 1454924798;

new Firebase("https://popping-fire-7751.firebaseio.com/")
    .startAt(startTime)
    .endAt(endTime)
    .once('value', show);
```

can anybody help me on what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Don't base your work on an outdated sample please. Nowadays you can filter in any child with `orderByChild('timestamp').startAt(startTime).endAt(endTime)`. There is no need to use priorities anymore.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen Your answer helped and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to skip a level in your JSON tree:

```
var startTime = 1454924792;
var endTime = 1454924798;

new Firebase("https://popping-fire-7751.firebaseio.com/")
    .child('device488')
    .startAt(startTime)
    .endAt(endTime)
    .once('value', show);
```

I highly recommend that you don't depend on the implicit priority anymore and instead just filter using `orderByChild()`

```
new Firebase("https://popping-fire-7751.firebaseio.com/")
    .child('device488')
    .orderByChild('timestamp')
    .startAt(startTime)
    .endAt(endTime)
    .once('value', show);
```

You'll need to add an index to your Security Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "device488": {
      ".indexOn": ["timestamp"]
    }
  }
}
```

But the more explicit behavior is well worth the effort of adding this.